# How to download all tweets from where it stopped using Phirehose? (streaming api twitter)

Tags: streaming, twitter

I'm using Phirehose for doing the streaming from some hashtags from twitter. But if my internet connection goes down I miss the tweets from the time it was down.

I need to know if there is a way to download all tweets from the point It stopped when my connection was down using only the streaming API.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **count** parameter with the [streaming API](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/post/statuses/filter) to get historical statuses, however you need elevated access (such as Firehose, Retweet, Link, Birddog or Shadow), and you [cannot use](http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-development-talk/msg/53e9951d2bc9df1e) the **track** parameter at the same time. Otherwise, you can only get statuses from after the point you connect to the endpoint.

Without additional access you'll need to backfill from the REST API in order to get historical tweets.

I went into a bit more detail regarding the **count** parameter [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5695564/get-all-past-tweets-via-twitter-streaming-api/5697315#5697315).