# Downloading twitter data using Flume

Tags: twitter, flume, tweets

Whenever I download tweets using flume all the downloaded tweets are the tweets that are tweeted after the query is run. Is there any way to download the tweets which are already tweeted before running the query??
for example if I run a query at 9.00am then the tweets that are created after 9am will only be downloaded.How can I download the tweets that are created before 9am?

Answer (score 0):

Flume uses Twitter streaming API, using streaming API you can't get old tweets.

Comment: Is there any way by which I can download old tweets?

Comment: Use search API, then your application will be more of batch processing application not a streaming application. 
Seems like there is some way to get [old tweets using streaming api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5695564/get-all-past-tweets-via-twitter-streaming-api) .